# JMF. Create new custom streamdatasource

Tags: java, jmf

I am looking to create a means of building a DataSource object (and hence a Processor) that gets data from a stream instead of a file, RTP, and so on.  I am writing a module for a much larger application that is meant to transparently transcode audio data. Going through the JMF docs only specify how to create a source from file however I need to be able to create a source from a stream within my application.

Any idea where I can start looking?

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/solutions/index.html) a few of the things you might need are implemented here, but if you look for more complicated things... I know I have lately, and didn't find any, I had to test these complicated things, step by step, by myself.

Hope this helps,

Adam.